# OrientDB failed to synchronize Luncene index

Tags: indexing, lucene, synchronization, orientdb

I am running a large integration test suite using embedded orientdb server with cleanup after every test. However, at some point the tests failed due to some fts indexes has been deleted while another trying to access them. As a result I received:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-11" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: _2.fdt
    at org.apache.lucene.search.ControlledRealTimeReopenThread.run(ControlledRealTimeReopenThread.java:247)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: _2.fdt
    at org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory.fileLength(FSDirectory.java:261)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentCommitInfo.sizeInBytes(SegmentCommitInfo.java:141)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriterPerThread.sealFlushedSegment(DocumentsWriterPerThread.java:529)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriterPerThread.flush(DocumentsWriterPerThread.java:502)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriter.doFlush(DocumentsWriter.java:506)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriter.flushAllThreads(DocumentsWriter.java:616)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.getReader(IndexWriter.java:370)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.StandardDirectoryReader.doOpenFromWriter(StandardDirectoryReader.java:288)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.StandardDirectoryReader.doOpenIfChanged(StandardDirectoryReader.java:263)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.StandardDirectoryReader.doOpenIfChanged(StandardDirectoryReader.java:253)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.DirectoryReader.openIfChanged(DirectoryReader.java:170)
    at org.apache.lucene.search.SearcherManager.refreshIfNeeded(SearcherManager.java:118)
    at org.apache.lucene.search.SearcherManager.refreshIfNeeded(SearcherManager.java:58)
    at org.apache.lucene.search.ReferenceManager.doMaybeRefresh(ReferenceManager.java:176)
    at org.apache.lucene.search.ReferenceManager.maybeRefreshBlocking(ReferenceManager.java:253)
    at org.apache.lucene.search.ControlledRealTimeReopenThread.run(ControlledRealTimeReopenThread.java:245)
```

Any one know how to fix this problem?

Comment: What type of operations are you performing exactly? It's difficult to understand where is the problem only with this log. Thanks.

Comment: Which version of OrientDB? How do you perform the clean up?

Comment: Thanks for replying. I am using com.orientechnologies:orientdb-server:2.1.16 and com.orientechnologies:orientdb-lucene:2.1.16. This dependencies contain embedded version of the database which provide option to clean everything in $ORIENTDB_HOME on startup